# Express difference between cookie-Sessions and connect-cookie-session

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

I am implementing a system where session data is stored in the cookie. This system doesn't require a memorystore or redis support which makes it attractive. However, I am confused on which middleware to add.

Should I add the default [cookieSession()](https://github.com/caolan/cookie-sessions) which comes bundled with connect or the third party [connect-cookie-session](https://github.com/jpallen/connect-cookie-session).

Oh and I am running the latest node version(0.8.16) and express version(3.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect-cookie-session` didn't have any commits for more than a year. That's a good indicator of an abandoned project, especially since there still are two open issues on the issue tracker (meaning it's not inactive because there's nothing that can be done better). It also has 2 pull requests pending acceptation for some time now.

I'd go with the default one.

Comment: Forget to check. Thanks for the help. By the way, can you tell me how strong cookieSessions are security-wise?

Comment: @shash7 looked into the code - it uses aes192 so I guess should be allright. Yu can always change it if you want.